# Can't select date in calendar and Gmail not coming to phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, gmail, calendar

My question is 2 fold:

First, when I go into calendar monthly view and hit say the 15h of the month...it won't pull up the info that day.  When I do a battery pull, it will work for a few hours then do the not working bit again.

Second, I have two emails going to my phone.  My personal Gmail and my work email that also used Gmail.  I have the work one set up as Priority but it only recieves about 1/16 of the emails that I get.

Any help for these issues would be great!  (I had currently upgraded to the Galaxy S2 LTE and didn't have these problems before with the Galaxy Nexium or whatever it was that I had...)